# Custom validation is return true || false but dont showing error styles and message

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

Appreciate any helps!

1. Plugin page: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/
2. When submit form doesn't validate, but the custom validation is
   returning correctly (open the console to see happening)
3. When checked some options is validating ok, but is redundant (2
   errors messages)

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <select id="variationType[]" name="variationType[]" class="multiple-select form-control" data-minselected="1" data-placeholder="Select one or more options" multiple required>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="4">Option 3</option>
        <option value="8">Option 4</option>
      </select>
      <small class="help-block with-errors"></small>
      <span class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Valid</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.multiple-select').multiselect({
  buttonContainer: '<div class="multiselect-group"></div>',
  buttonClass: 'form-control',
  nonSelectedText: !$(this).attr('data-placeholder') ? 'Selecionar' : $(this).attr('data-placeholder'),
  numberDisplayed: 1
});

$.fn.validator.Constructor.INPUT_SELECTOR = ':input:not([type="submit"], button):enabled';
$('form').validator({
  delay: 200,
  focus: false,
  feedback: {
    success: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign',
    error: 'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign'
  },
  custom: {
    minselected: function($el) {
            console.log(!!$.trim($el.val()));
      return !!$.trim($el.val());
    }
  },
  errors: {
    minselected: "Select one or more options"
  }
});
```

Fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/9ts4nvhw/4/

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably new syntax in the latest validator code (I ran into it with validator v0.11.9).

What is supposed to be returned by the custom validator is the error message, not whether the field is valid (true/false). The errors object is no longer needed at all (though I guess you could include it -- doesn't seem to make a difference).

For example:

```
$('form').validator({
    delay: 200,
    focus: false,
    feedback: {
        success: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign',
        error: 'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign'
    },
    custom: {
        minselected: function($el) {
              console.log(!!$.trim($el.val()));
              return !!$.trim($el.val()) && "Select one or more options";
        }
    }
});
```